# mongoose deep copy object using lowdash

Tags: mongoose, underscore.js, clone, deep-copy

Rather than the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` trick, I tried to lowdash's `deepClone()` to clone a object in mongoose.  However, deepClone chokes on bson ObjectID.

I tried,

```
var copy = _.cloneDeep(workout, function(value){
  if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(value)) {
    return value.toString();
  }
});
```

But no dice.  Any suggestion on the right way to do this?